# updating components on different page in primefaces 3.x

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I am currently migrating our app from primefaces 2.21 to 3.2. i am aware that there are many new changes with 3.2. I am trying to update a dialog with ajax request like below.

```
   <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    //namespaces
   template="MainTemplate.xhtml">
   <ui:include src="dlgpath"/>
   <h:form id="formId">
   <p:datatable id="tab1">
     <p:column> 
     <p:commandButton id="mdf" value="modify" oncomplete="dlg.show();"         
    update="dlgfrmid"/>
     </p:column>
   </datatable>
    </h:form>
```

below is the code for the dialog

```
    <p:dialog  widgetVar="dlg">
      <h:form id="dlgfrmid">
      <p:panelGrid id="gridId"> </p:panelGrid>
      <p:commandButton></p:commandButton>
      </h:form>
       </p:dialog>
```

i am getting the "infamous" Cannot find component with identifier "dlgfrmid" in the view error message
i have done a lot of search, can some one help me understand the concept of component referencing in PF 3.x ...

thanks 
any help appreciated

Comment: 1 ) you should place p:column inside datatable and place <p:commandButton inside the p:column 2 ) you should assign widgeVar="dlg" to p:dialog ... 3) you should look into the showcase , cause it seems that you lack some basic stuff... 4) post more code in the question

Comment: @Daniel i have done all of those, apologies for not posting precise code. i just want to understand how would update attribute will update the form in the dialog in PF3.x

Comment: what is that element with infamous id ? cause your current code seems fine

Comment: @Daniel i tried update=":dlgfrmid" already daniel. it isnt working. still getting the same message

Comment: show entire content of <ui:include src="dlgpath"/>
also try to take the <p:dialog  widgetVar="dlg">.... out of seperate file and place it after the  </h:form> in the main page to see if the update=":dlgfrmid" works , also ... any chance that src="dlgpath" is a wrong path ? do you see its content in the view source?

Comment: @Daniel if i put the dialog in the same xhtml it works fine , i can see the content of the dialog in view source. just want to know how can we update the components in a different page with update ....

Comment: post your entire content of the external page , and check if you see the dialog in the "view source" when you include that external page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
<p:dialog  widgetVar="dlg">
```

into

```
<p:dialog appendToBody="true" widgetVar="dlg">
```

and

```
<p:commandButton id="mdf" value="modify" oncomplete="dlg.show();"         
update="dlgfrmid"/>
```

into

```
<p:commandButton id="mdf" value="modify" oncomplete="dlg.show();"         
update=":dlgfrmid"/>
```

I've had a similar problem and I solved this by appending the dialog to body's html

Comment: @Daniel, StepTNT.. thanks a lot for your responses. it finally worked .. :)

Comment: You're welcome!
Remember to use `:` before an id if the components are not in the same name container (as in your case) !